# HTTPS Gateway API Proxying Requests over HTTP

Tags: node.js, express, http, https, proxy

I have a question regarding network traffic.

I have an express node API acting as an HTTPS Gateway API (listening on port 443) that proxies requests to various express microservices on the same computer listening on various other ports.

The microservices are all http, and only the HTTPS gateway API can communicate to them via the proxied requests.

Is the traffic from the gateway API to the microservices still encrypted because the initial request had to pass through the HTTPS gateway before being proxied to the microservice?

I'm just curious what's going on under the hood there and whether or not this is bad practice.
Again, due to various firewall protections, none of the http microservices are accessible unless the first pass through the HTTPS gateway.

Here is a very basic illustration of the flow as I understand it:[image: HTTPS to HTTP proxy flow]

If this is bad practice, I'd like to know what I can do to better secure these proxy communications. I've tried making the microservices HTTPS by having them apply the same cert the gateway API is using, but then I run into certificate chain issues.

Thanks for any help!

Comment: The traffic from the gateway API to the microservices is _not_ encrypted, because the Gateway terminates TLS and creates a new, unencrypted request. If this is a request to `localhost` (the same computer on a different port), this is less dangerous than if the request went over the internet.

Comment: Thanks for the clarification! Just so I'm clear, once the Gateway receives the response from the microservice, passing the response from the gateway back to the client remains encrypted over HTTPS, right?

Comment: Yes, the response from Gateway to Client goes over the encrypted connection.